# No locking-error workflow found in Aviarc

Tags: xml, aviarc

Can someone please tell me the reason for the following error. Thanks.

```
HTTP ERROR: 500
An error has occurred     : CommandException: No locking-error workflow found: tried 'system/locking-error' and 'locking-error'
caused by                 : NoSuchWorkflowException: Unable to retrieve workflow 'system/locking-error': No workflow called "system/locking-error"

Source context:
Application    : crm-test
Workflow    : settings
Element        : atomic-commit
URI            :
Line           : 6
Column        : -1
Path        : /workflow[1]/atomic-commit[1]
  settings.xml : line 1 : <workflow>
  main-page.xml : line 2 : <show-screen>
  main-page.xml : line 1 : <workflow>
  start.xml : line 3 : <call-workflow>
  start.xml : line 1 : <workflow>

Request context:
Request URI: /aviarc/crm-test/22A91EF8DA66B0544BE7F58B3FC011F7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two errors here:

1. **There was a problem during an `<atomic-commit>`.** For some reason your update did not affect any rows.
2. **You haven't created a locking-error handler workflow at workflows/system/locking-error.xml.** If you are implementing optimistic locking, [it would pay to create one](http://dev.aviarc.com/docs/aviarc/dev_guide/optimistic_locking).

In any case, this error is often cause by *something other than a locking error*. Have a look at your create/update/delete query; perhaps you thought it would update a row but there's a logic error in your query and it's affecting zero rows.

If you don't intend to use optimistic locking, you can disable it for that particular commit like so:

```
<atomic-commit optimistic-locking="n">
  <dataset name="foo"/>
</atomic-commit>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, atomic-commit assumes that all commits will be made with optimistic locking, and if the database tells it that a commit query didn't affect any rows it assumes that the lock failed and attempts to call the system workflow 'locking-error'.